# How to resolve a DegradedArray event when one drive has been permanently removed from RAID array?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

When I installed my VPS some months ago (Ubuntu 18.04), the default RAID configuration was relying on 3 disks. I removed /dev/sdc from the array to create a new partition. RAID array is now as below:

```
~# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Nov 16 19:46:26 2019
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 305152 (298.00 MiB 312.48 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 305152 (298.00 MiB 312.48 MB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Mon Mar 30 00:00:03 2020
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : 163-172-103-121:0
              UUID : b4acac7e:de2c1e5c:e43cc0ba:ad662e4a
            Events : 310

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       -       0        0        2      removed
```

As a result, the RAID array is still sync'ed on two disks, BUT I receive a daily "DegradedArray event" email.

And I didn't fid the right way to fix it, I mean to mark RaidDevice 2 as permanently removed. And to be honest, I am afraid of broking something ;)

Please let me know how to proceed.

Thanks ! 
++

Answer (score 0):

`mdadm` calls this procedure "growing".  You want to "grow" the array to have two disks instead of three:

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=2
```

As always, before making a major change to a RAID volume, make sure you have backups!

Comment: It worked, thank you !